# Xamarin Native Android Checkbox Not Displaying in PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my PCL in Xamarin, I am trying to implement a native Android checkbox. However, when I compile the code, all that is displayed is a blank page with a white background. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
         xmlns:androidForms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
         x:Class="Namespace"
         Title="Title">
    <ContentPage Title="Tab">
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="White">
            <android:CheckBox x:Arguments="{x:Static androidForms:Forms.Context}" />
        </ContentView>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Xamarin Native Android Checkbox Not Displaying in PCL

Make sure there's no `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in your `TabbedPage`.

```
//[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

After comment out this line, the `Checkbox` can be displayed in my project.